# I want to create a file which will take header of 1.csv and rest all data from 2.csv .In Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

1.csv ---> only header, 2.csv ---> 8 GB file.
From below coding I am getting again header after 100000 rows and some of data is also missing.

```
$process_Dir = 'E:\Pushpendra\HIPPA_File\'
    (Get-Content $process_Dir\1.csv | Select -First 1 | Out-File -Append $process_Dir\new.csv -Encoding utf8)
    (Get-Content $process_Dir\2.csv -ReadCount 100000) |Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append $process_Dir\new.csv -Encoding utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Since apparently your second CSV file is quite large, I'd suggest reading the file using `switch -File` for fast performance and write the data lines using a StreamWriter object.

Something like this:

```
$process_Dir = 'E:\Pushpendra\HIPPA_File'
# create a new file with just the first line (the column headers) from '1.csv'
Get-Content -Path "$process_Dir\1.csv" -TotalCount 1 | 
    Set-Content -Path "$process_Dir\new.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Force

# next, add the data lines from the second csv file to this
# because this is a very large file, we're using a streamwriter to add the lines
$stream   = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("$process_Dir\new.csv", $true)  # $true means append
$skipLine = $true  # a boolean variable to skip the header line in 2.csv
switch -File "$process_Dir\2.csv" {
    default { if ($skipLine) { $skipLine = $false } else { $stream.WriteLine($_) } }
}
# dispose the StreamWriter object
$stream.Flush()
$stream.Dispose()
```

Comment: I am only left with header, no files been added

Comment: @PushpendraSingh Cannot reproduce that. In my tests, this works as you asked. Are you giving the code enough time to finish adding the rows from the large `2.csv` file to the new `new.csv` file?

Comment: @PushpendraSingh You may also try setting `$stream.AutoFlush = $true` after defining the streamwriter object.

Comment: Yes, I  am giving enough time, after completing program I am opening file, but it's not working. I am getting new.csv with header only.

Comment: @PushpendraSingh again.. I can't reproduce that. Ate you sure you read the correct files?

Comment: yes ofc, can we connect over google meet, send me invitation on email:- pushpendra1995@gmail.com

Comment: @PushpendraSingh Sorry, I don't email on SO questions. Any update on this? Try with a smaller `2.csv` first to see the results faster. Any error messages?